# AWS lambda upload file to API via python/curl wont recognize tmp file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

can someone explain why my python code is failing to upload file to an api

`logger.info("is videofilethere : {} \n".format(os.path.isfile('/tmp/' + videoFileName + '.mp4')))`

> [INFO]    2017-10-23T05:59:26.274Z    52e8b51d-b7b7-11e7-b687-450a720c44f3    is
>   videofilethere : True

but

[ERROR] 2017-10-23T05:59:26.278Z    52e8b51d-b7b7-11e7-b687-450a720c44f3    [Errno 2]

> No such file or directory

```
result = subprocess.call("curl -X POST \
--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header Authorization: Bearer sometoken \
-F asset='{ \"folderId\": \"12345\", \
\"name\": \"blH\", \
\"description\": \"Cool new Asset!\", \
\"text\": \"Text body.\", \
\"EntityType\": \"Asset\"}' \
;type=application/json' \
-F video=@/tmp/somefile.mp4 \
-F videoSize=7689755} \
\"https://api.blahblah/12345/asset?multipart\" \
")
return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your `/tmp/somefile.mp4`.

`subprocess.call` can't find `curl`. You should use `shell=True` in your `call`. Here is a simplified example:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    import subprocess
    result = subprocess.call("curl -I http://google.com", shell=True)
    return result
```